# does Query.Timeout override MaxQueryTimeout?

Tags: 2013, search

When setting [`Timeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.query.timeout.aspx) on a [`KeywordQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.keywordquery_members.aspx), does this override [`MaxQueryTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.searchserviceapplication.maxquerytimeout.aspx) on the [`SearchServiceApplication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.server.search.administration.searchserviceapplication.aspx)?

I.e. does it make sense to do

```
KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(site);
query.QueryText = "ContentClass:STS_Site";
query.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
...
```

Or is it better to limit the timeout according to the SearchServiceApplication

```
KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(site);
query.QueryText = "ContentClass:STS_Site";
query.Timeout = GoFindMySSA().GetSearchServiceApplicationInfo().MaxQueryTimeout;
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has no info on this topic. But [MS-QSSWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd952828(v=office.12).aspx) [clearly states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd943107(v=office.12).aspx):

> **MaxQueryTimeout**: Specifies the maximum allowed timeout value in **QueryProperties.Timeout**, as specified in section [2.2.4.11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd954742(v=office.12).aspx). MUST be greater than value specified for **DefaultQueryTimeout**.

Tests show, however, that `Query.Timeout` (in SSOM!) indeed overrides `SearchServiceApplicationInfo.MaxQueryTimeout`. I.e. by Setting `query.Timeout = int.MaxValue;` the query will wait for a really long time (about 24 days) before timing out - regardless of the value of `SearchServiceApplicationInfo.MaxQueryTimeout`.

*On a sidenote*: Using SSOM it is not possible to set a value `Query.RowLimit` that exceeds `SearchServiceApplicationInfo.MaxRowLimit`. Trying to do so will raise `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.
Using CSOM, however, it *is* possible to set a value for `Query.RowLimit` that exceeds `SearchServiceApplicationInfo.MaxRowLimit`: The value will be silently ignored and `SearchServiceApplicationInfo.MaxRowLimit` will be used insted. To make matters worse: Setting `query.Timeout` larger than `SearchServiceApplicationInfo.MaxQueryTimeout` will fail in CSOM and raise a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException`